# CSS table / table-cell and padding?

Tags: css

I was wondering why using padding on a "display: table;" was not working as I expect it should ;-).

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background: firebrick;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    background: seagreen;
}

<div class="table">
  <div class="table-cell">
    Why is the padding working like shit?
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7n38t/

As you can see the "padding: 10px;" on ".table" is resulting in a table that is bigger than the frame... and the horizontal scrollbar appears.

Why is it reacting like this?? I don't want a workaround for this, because I have one, but I really want to understand why!

Thanks,
Bastien

Comment: Because the box model is different between browsers. Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera will not include padding as part of the calculation of width. IE will though. + why are you using divs for a table?

Comment: @David Nguyen: It was 15 years ago. It isn't today unless you're still relying on IE5 quirks mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting box-sizing to border box will fix your issue:

check it out in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7n38t/3/

```
.table {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    background: firebrick;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* this guy!! */
}
.table-cell {
    display: table-cell;
    background: seagreen;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you set the width and height properties of an element with CSS, you just set the width and height of the content area. To calculate the full size of an element, you must also add the padding, borders and margins.

Ref:http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use border-spacing instead of padding on your table element (the box model behaves differently for tables).

```
border-spacing:10px;
```